# Changing DNS Name checking

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, dkim

using windows 2003 Server with DNS service brought me to the option of "name checking". Our current setting is "RFC only". This settings prohibits names with underscore at the beginning, which is needed for DKIM and Domainkeys. The help text in the DNS Management console says that changing that property could cause changes in the files of the zone. What does that mean? Is it dangerous to change this setting?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it states that it may reslut in changes in the zone files is that if you are going from a less strict, to more strict checking mode, then DNS records that do not meet that criteria may be altered. If you are relaxing the constraints on name checking then this should not be an issue.